# swift 3.0: tableview cannot show data which received as JSON through web api

Tags: json, swift, tableview

i started to learn IOS development using swift 3.0.i built a simple app to call  web api to query data from server database. i can get the json data and parsed it into string array. the App can print the array, but it cannot show in the tableview. it confused me several days and i searched some examples and answers on internet but still couldn't work out it.
My codes as below:

```
class LocationTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var names: [String] = []  

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //——————————————————————————get the data from web api and using json parsing————————————————————————
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default // Session Configuration
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config) // Load configuration into Session
    let url = URL(string: "http://XXXXXXX/api/mylocations")!

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in            
        if error != nil {                
            print(error!.localizedDescription)                
        } else {                
            do {                    
                var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
                let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray
                jsonResult = jsonArray.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray                    
                var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()                    

                for i in 0..<jsonResult.count {                        
                    jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary                  
                    if let name = jsonElement["Name"] as? String                       
                    {
                        //  print(id)
                        //  print(name)
                        //  print(address)
                        // print(latitude)
                        // print(longitude)
                        // print("-------")
                        self.names.append(name)
                    }                                                
                    // self.tableView.reloadData()
                    // print(self.names)
                }                    
              print(self.names)
               // can print the string array data like [“name1”,”name2”,”name3”]                    
            } catch {                    
                print("error in JSONSerialization")                    
            }
        }            
    })

    task.resume()        
    //-------------- ———  result is [] it seems the above code didn't put the string array to names.——————————————
    print(self.names)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
          return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count;
}

internal override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for:
    indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell
        // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]
   return cell    

    }
}
```

Can anyone help me have a look?

Comment: Please cleanup the code posted, remove all the commented out code, useless `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, less empty lines, so it is easier for the reader

Answer (score 1):

Put `self.tableView.reloadData()` after print `print(self.names)`.

Comment: I tried put self.tableView.reloadData() but still didn't work.Thanks!

Comment: @user7505698 Try to reload tableView on main thread. `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }`

Comment: this on main queue is the solution

Comment: Thank you so much @NiravD! it works well now using your suggestion.

Comment: @user7505698 Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you have commented...

> result is [] it seems the above code didn't put the string array to
>   names

This line of code is being executed **before** the data has been downloaded within the completion handler, so we wouldn't expect to see anything here.  You will note that it **is** working on the other print that you have within the completion handler.

The `tableView.reloadData()` at the end of the completion handler should be working.

Are you sure that you have the delegates set up correctly for the tableView?  What do you see if you comment out the download task, and simply set

```
names = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"]
```

within `viewDidLoad` ?  If that doesn't work, it's a problem with the delegates.